# How does this bash script know the files in my current directory?

Tags: bash, glob

While reading the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf) I came across the following example:

```
select fname in *;
do
    echo you picked $fname \($REPLY\)
    break;
done
```

The output of the script is the following:

```
1) case1.sh
2) loop1.sh
3) loop2.sh
4) select1.sh
#? 3
you picked loop2.sh (3)
```

All the options given are the files of the directory I'm running the script from (`select1.sh`).
My question is how does the script know the contents of my current working directory?

My guess would be that the `*` token is responsible for it.

Comment: Your guess would be correct. The shell expands wildcards automatically.

Comment: Try just `echo *` and you'll see it.

Comment: @Barmar so is * similar to the `ls` command in this context ?

Comment: It's similar in all contexts.

Comment: `ls *`, `cat *`, `echo *` in all of them the `*` is expanded to all filenames (except dot-files by default).

Comment: See [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) in the manual.

Comment: And just be aware you can run into problems with too many files sometimes - `ls -laF /Users/foo/*/*/*/*
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (wildcard pattern) that expands to the names of all the files in the current working directory (excluding hidden files [by default](https://askubuntu.com/a/259386/301745)). You can demonstrate this easily by running `echo *`, which should produce this output:

```
case1.sh loop1.sh loop2.sh select1.sh
```

This is documented in the Bash manual under [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).